# ".NET 5.0 out of support" ASP.NET framework problem

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I want to work with Visual Studio 2019 .NET 5.0 Framework but there is a little message like this on page:

> (Net 5.0 out of support).

Is .NET 5.0 framework banned from Microsoft? Or just sort of cancelled?

Comment: Like the error message tells you, it is out of support. Googling this error message easily brings you more information.

Comment: This is Microsoft's way of telling you "if you have a problem or encounter a bug with .NET 5, we aren't going to help you - upgrade to the latest .NET version and try again."

Answer (score 1):

As Timothy G said. Microsoft will no longer provide servicing updates for .NET 5.0, including security fixes or technical support, and users will need to update their .NET version to a supported version (.NET 6.0) to continue receiving updates.

[image]

.NET 5.0 is not an LTS release, so will end support 18 months after release or 6 months after the next release. When .NET 5.0 support ends, applications using this version will continue to work, but the related vulnerabilities may not be fixed as Microsoft only provides support for the supported versions of .NET (ie. .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6.0) Release a security update. Therefore users are strongly advised to migrate their applications to .NET 6.0.

**Upgrade to .NET 6.0**

1. Open the project file (.csproj, .vbproj or *.fsproj file).
2. Change the target framework value from net5.0 to net6.0, the target framework is defined by the or element.
3. For more migration matters, please refer to the .NET 6 Compatibility Guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0.

Visual Studio 16.11 will continue to support .NET 5.0 SDK versions until the end of support for .NET Core 3.1 in December 2022. However, the .NET 5.0 SDK does not use the .NET 5.0 runtime when running command-line scenarios, and is not available as a standalone SDK. It is recommended to use .NET 6.0 and Visual Studio 2022 to build applications that run on supported .NET runtimes.

For more support content, please view the official announcement: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-5-end-of-support-update/.